# c++ lambda capture the context by reference and also the `this` pointer

Tags: c++, lambda

Is it possible to capture the context by reference and also the `this` pointer with a lambda function?

It seems that the code below does not work. How can I do that?

```
[&, this] () { }
```

Comment: Define "does not work" and show us why you think so.

Comment: If you check [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) you will see that "The only capture defaults are **&** (implicitly catch the odr-used automatic variables and this by reference) and **=** (implicitly catch the odr-used automatic variables and this by value)." This means if you provide only `&` or `=` as capture you will also capture `this`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It "works" just fine m8:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    int y;

    T() : y(0)
    {
        int x = 0;
        [&, this](){ x = 1; y = 2; }();

        std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';  // 1 2
    }
};

int main()
{
    T t;
}
```

It's actually redundant to specify `this`, as `&` already captures it.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee439ddd4fa4d964))

Comment: I have local variables in my class method. Should I capture local variables with copying?

Comment: @Narek: If you want to...?!

Comment: I mean if I don't capture local variables by copying them they will be not initialized (will contain garbage) in the lambda function?

Comment: @Narek: If you call the lambda after the function returns (destroying the local variables), then the references will be invalid - so you must capture by value if you might do that. If you only call the lambda from within the function, then either is fine, depending on the semantics you need.

Comment: @Narek: Capturing by reference is sometimes fine, otherwise it wouldn't have been added to the language. What Mike said.